# How to clone repository for Eclipse Equinox?

Tags: eclipse, equinox

I’m trying to clone the repository for the Eclipse Equinox Bundles. It says on the [Resources page](http://eclipse.org/equinox/bundles/resources.php) to use either [web access](http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.bundles.git/) or direct access over SSH at:
ssh://anonymous@git.eclipse.org/gitroot/equinox/rt.equinox.bundles.git

However, the links aren’t working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already worked out a solution when I had my question written, so here it goes.

Use HTTPS to clone the Git repo:
https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.bundles.git/